# Is the Goblet sapient or how does it judge worthiness?

Tags: harry-potter

There is enchanted stuff that does simple 'scripted' actions like portraits that ask for a password or girls dorm corridors that reject boys entering. I guess the Goblet of Fire should be a strong judge of character, and therefore should be intelligent (rather than scripted) the way only a human can.

Is the Goblet a fully synthetic (not a human soul) object that is wise enough to judge people?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The Sorting Hat is most certainly intelligent. With the Goblet, it is less certain. Perhaps you should limit your question to that.

Comment: @Jonah thanks, I removed the reference to Sorting Hat to contain the scope of the question.

Comment: The portraits are intelligent, by the way.

Comment: Maybe the Goblet is a graphology expert and can judge one's character based on his/her handwriting.

Answer (score 5):

### Unclear, but it seems to have some degree of intelligence

The Goblet of Fire is described as a selector, which gives the impression of agency:

> “As you know, three champions compete in the tournament,” Dumbledore
>   went on calmly, “one from each of the participating schools. They will
>   be marked on how well they perform each of the Tournament tasks and
>   the champion with the highest total after task three will win the
>   Triwizard Cup. The champions will be chosen by an impartial selector:
>   the Goblet of Fire.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

The Goblet also apparently judges how "worthy" a contestant is:

> Tomorrow  night, Halloween, the goblet will return the names of the
>   three **it has judged most worthy** to represent their schools.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Tellingly, Dumbledore describes that Goblet as *making decisions*:

> “Well, the goblet is almost ready **to make its decision**,” said
>   Dumbledore. “I estimate that it requires one more minute.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

This could be a mere turn of phrase, but it seems to indicate that the Goblet possesses intelligence.

Moody (really Bartemius Crouch Junior in disguise), gives us the biggest clue:

> “Because they **hoodwinked a very powerful magical object**!” said Moody.
>   “It would have needed an exceptionally strong Confundus Charm to
>   **bamboozle that goblet into forgetting** that only three schools compete
>   in the tournament. . . . I’m guessing they submitted Potter’s name
>   under a fourth school, to make sure he was the only one in his
>   category. . . .”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Moody seems to be describing the Goblet as a conscious entity, one that can be bamboozled and hoodwinked, and would otherwise "remember" that only three schools compete. In addition, elsewhere in the series, the Confundus Charm has only ever been seen used on people, not inanimate objects.

**It seems likely that the Goblet possesses some degree of intelligence, but how much is unclear.**

Answer (score 1):

We don't know much about the Goblet (see Jonah's excellent answer for the rundown) but we DO know about a similarly functioning object - the Hogwarts' Sorting Hat. As per Pottermore (cited in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10205/976)) the hat is somewhat sapient, and has legilemency skills.

While we aren't told specifically, the Goblet is quite possibly very similar in nature.

Comment: It struck me that there's a very real possibility that the Goblet of Fire is simply a random number generator and the whole "choosing the most worthy person" is just marketing spiel